# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The break point is not hit and this error when browsing the page. The `GetFilters` function is called at Page Load.
If the line, where datatable is converted to list is commented, the page loads fine without error.

```
public static void GetFilters(out List<Set> lstSets)
{
    lstSets = null;
    DataSet ds = Getdata();

    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lstSets = ds.Tables[0].DataTableToList<Set>();
        }          
    }
}
```

**Helper.cs**

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            T obj = new T();
            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], 
                                    propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;                     
     }
 }
```

**Error:**

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'Helper.DataTableToList<Set>(System.Data.DataTable)' and 
'Helper.DataTableToList<Set>(System.Data.DataTable)'
```

I commented the line `lstSets = ds.Tables[0].DataTableToList<Set>();`, put the breakpoint for `GetFilters`. The breakpoint is now hit and while debugging using F10, I removed the comment and stragely it worked fine and the page loaded normally.

Where am i going wrong.

Comment: Did you move the method around in the code recently? Maybe changed project? Try cleaning the project and rebuilding everything.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are actually having references to 2 different versions of the same assembly (strong named?). Either directly references or one of your assemblies is using another version of the same assembly you are using.

So you have 2 different versions of either DataTableToList or Set somehow loaded at the same time.

Comment: The returned dataset result has only Id & name whereas the `Set` class has many other props. as well defined along with Id & name. Could this be a reason. Also, it is just a test app. I am unable to find the 2nd ref. if any.

Comment: That assembly containing Helper.DataTableToList(), do you have any other classes with the same name or method. Do the assembly reside in GAC? If not, try cleaning the project. Also try deleting all the content of all the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder you have under c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework*. Might be an older version of your assembly being used. When it fails, try breaking your code and look at all your loaded modules, see if you can see your assembly loaded more than once. Dirty option: Rename your helper class. That will stop your code from using any older versions of that class

Comment: No Other class or method with same name. But I still have renamed the Helper class to Extensions and also the method name. No Luck. I also checked the Temp ASP.Net files but do not find any folder with current project name.

Comment: Search your code for all "DataTableToList" functions. My guess is that you have 2 extension methods lying around. Identical. Either in your assembly or also in another. Try renaming the DataTableToList method name if you can not find the duplicate.

Comment: :) I couldn't find any in the project. So I renamed it to ConvertDataTableToList. Still the same. So I created a new project and it works fine here. What are my options now. I cannot create a whole new working project again.

Comment: Weird. Try cleaning out all your using statements in the helper class and only add the ones you need. Explicitly define with full namespace each of the classes used in the function definition. Instead of DataTable, use System.Data.DataTable. Instead of List<T>, use its full name with namespace:  System.Collections.Generic.List<T> etc. I dont think there would be any issues with different versions of .Net DataTable, but if you are using DataTables created in another assembly, the .Net version might be off...? ( i doubt it tho )

Answer (score -2):

This error occurs when the runtime is seeing the same method defined more than once in the same namespace.